# UIScrollView with 3 UITableViews

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I made a UIScrollView like the Weather.app.

On the first page I've placed a UITableView which shows data loaded from a website. On the second and on the third page I also want to place a UITableView. The other two tables should also load data from a website, but from another URL.

How can I set up a UIScrollView with 3 UITableViews in it?

Answer (score 0):

The question does not sound quite like the description - do you want separate pages for the table views (in which case they are simply tableviewControllers) ?

If you want three tableviews within one UIScroll view I'd go through a number of thuoght processes

1) Is this really what you want : would you be better with one table view with multiple sections ?

2) If this is really what you want - create a tableViewController for each tableview (alloc/init), then add the views from each of those to your scrollview.

`[self.scrollview addSubview:tableViewController1.view];`

you will need to set the frame etc of course to get it to display in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Try PanelTableView.
The code it open sourced. 
https://github.com/honcheng/PanelTableView
You can have multiple table views in one scrollviews.